# Simplify boolean expression

Tags: java, boolean, simplify

I have this bit of code and eclipse is telling me that the boolean expressions can be simplified.

```
    knightTurn == true && occupied ==true
```

and

```
    knightTurn == true
```

both boolean knightTurn and boolean occupied are set to false earlier in the code.

```
    boolean knightTurn=false

    boolean occupied=false

    @Tags({"passed"})
public void passed () 
{
    final int x = 50;
    if (knightTurn == true && occupied == true) {
        for (int i=0; i<x; i++) {
            standKnight.moveAvatar(i, 0);
            avatarEditor.refresh();
            i++;
        }
        occupied = false;
    }

}

@Tags({"failed"})
public void failed () {
    final int x = 35;
    if (knightTurn == true) {
        for (int i=0; i<x; i++) {
            standKnight.moveAvatar(i, i/2);
            avatarEditor.refresh();
            i++;
        }
        occupied =  false;
    }
```

The code still runs as it should, but how do I tidy up this bit and make it simpler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 if (knightTurn == true && occupied == true)
```

Can be written as

```
 if (knightTurn && occupied)
```

**This also reduces the possibility of making mistakes like these**

```
if (knightTurn = true)
```

Answer (score 3):

For a boolean, you can use it directly in the expression without explicitly evaluating it to true.

```
 if (someBooleanVariable && someOtherBoolean){
    // run condition

 }
```

Comment: It also can be written with logical AND like: `if (someBooleanVariable & someOtherBoolean)`

Comment: @Fede I advise against using the simple & for such tasks, use the && for AND